# Nginx over TLS with docker compose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, docker-swarm

**Info:**

- Nginx server
- Docker
- Docker-compose
- Docker swarm

**Current:**

My frontend is accessible over http. Everything works fine.

**What I want:**

I need to update to https.

**Problem:**

When I add the config data ( public and private key), it works fine local. When it
runs on docker swarm I get a 400 over **http** (from nginx), which is ok.

[image]

The Problem is that **https** doesn't works, it cannot reach the frontend. Something has to be wrong with my config in docker-compose I think.

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 8080 ssl;
        ssl_certificate     /cert/public.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /cert/private.key;

        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length 1000;
        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    }
}
```

Docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  my_network:
    external: true
services:
  microfrontend-root:
    image: ${CONTAINER_IMAGE}:single_spa_root-${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}-${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}
    volumes:
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    networks:
      my_network:
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.2'
          memory: ${MEMORY_LIMIT}
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.${SERVER_LABEL}==true
      labels:
        - "traefik.backend=dev_single_spa_root"
        - "traefik.port=8080"
        - "traefik.docker.network=my_network"
        - "traefik.frontend.tls=true"
        - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:my-host.net;PathPrefixStrip:/subpath/"
        - "com.application=MyName"
        - "com.component=single_spa_root"
        - "com.environment=dev"
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Just like that, if you already use Traefik, then you can simply use it to create an SSL certificate. Or is that not what you want? And your Nginx configuration looks kind of wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just an example:

```
server {

        server_name YOUR-DOMAIN.COM;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://IP-OR-NAME-FROM-YOUR-DOKCER-SERVICE:8080;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forward-Proto http;
                proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;

                proxy_redirect off;

        }
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate     /cert/public.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /cert/private.key;
}

# Redirect all to https
server {
    if ($host = YOUR-DOMAIN.COM) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name YOUR-DOMAIN.COM;
        return 404;
}
```